# Retrieving web part ID (GUID) with SharePoint REST API

Tags: web-part, rest, client-object-model

I need to get the ID of a web part on a page before I have redirected the browser to the page.

The reason for this is that I need to update a field value that contains web part settings, which are linked via the web part ID's. I can access the page field and update it through a POST-call using the REST API, but I have yet to find a way to retrieve the web part ID's on the page.

If the case was that I could load the page first, then it would have been simple to retrieve them with jQuery.

Is this possible, or do I have to find another way? Using CSOM would be an acceptable answer as long as it's done with JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the ID through [GetLimitedWebPartManager method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileGetLimitedWebPartManager)

You need file URL, the scope and something to filter by.
Here is an example:

```
_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Home.aspx')/GetLimitedWebPartManager(scope=1)/WebParts?$expand=WebPart&$filter=WebPart/Title+eq+'Test'
```